# how to handle Stale Element Reference Exception while finding element in JMeter

Tags: javascript, selenium-webdriver, automation, jmeter, staleelementreferenceexception

i am trying to find element whose structure something like  below

```
<div>
 <div>
  <div>
    <ul>
     <object id = "obj"
       #document (here is a link )
        <html>
         <head> </head>
          <body>
            <div id = style4 >
```

i have tried multiple ways to find this element but it always gives exception of stale element here's what i've done

```
 var table = wait.until(pkg.ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(pkg.By.xpath('/html/body/div[8]/div/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div/ul')));
    WDS.browser.executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", table);
    WDS.log.info("Got Table");

    // Find the <object> element within the table
    var objectElement = table.findElement(pkg.By.tagName('object'));
    WDS.log.info("Found objectElement");

    // Extract the content of the <object> element
    var objectContent = objectElement.getAttribute('data');
    WDS.log.info("Extracted objectContent");

    // Refresh the <object> element to prevent staleness
    WDS.browser.executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", objectElement);
    WDS.log.info("Refreshed objectElement");

    // Load the content document of the <object> element
    var contentDocument = WDS.browser.executeScript("return arguments[0].contentDocument", objectElement);
    WDS.log.info("Loaded contentDocument");

    // Find the <html> element within the content document
    var htmlElement = contentDocument.querySelector('html');
    WDS.log.info("Found htmlElement: " + htmlElement);
```

and this is the log

```
2024-02-21 22:42:12,278 INFO c.g.j.p.w.s.WebDriverSampler: Got Table
2024-02-21 22:42:12,289 INFO c.g.j.p.w.s.WebDriverSampler: Found objectElement
2024-02-21 22:42:12,304 INFO c.g.j.p.w.s.WebDriverSampler: Extracted objectContent
2024-02-21 22:42:12,309 INFO c.g.j.p.w.s.WebDriverSampler: Refreshed objectElement
2024-02-21 22:42:12,317 ERROR c.g.j.p.w.s.WebDriverSampler: Error: org.openqa.selenium.StaleElementReferenceException: stale element reference: stale element not found
  (Session info: chrome=122.0.6261.58)
```

Answer (score 0):

You've create the problem yourself by using the [JavascriptExecutor](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/JavascriptExecutor.html). Do you think that real user using the real browser will really open the browser developer tools, switch to console and type `var table = document.getElementById....)`? I strongly doubt.

- If you use JavaScript for scrolling you need to [find all the elements](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/elements/finders/) once more because the visible/interactable DOM has changed after the scroll event
- However I would recommend switching to [Actions API](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/actions_api/) and use i.e. [Actions.scrollToElement()](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/interactions/Actions.html#scrollToElement(org.openqa.selenium.WebElement)) instead

In any case you can protect yourself from StaleElementReference errors by using Explicit Wait for any element operation like instead of this:

```
var element = WDS.browser.findElement(pkg.By.id('foo'))
//something else
element.click()
```

you can do:

```
wait.until(pkg.ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(pkg.By.id('foo'))).click()
```

Also regarding using JavaScript - it might be not the best idea, in general it's [recommended to use JSR223 Test Elements and Groovy language for scripting](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#jsr223) in general because [Groovy provides the best performance](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/beanshell-vs-jsr223-vs-jmeter). Moreover [Nashorn engine has been removed in JDK 15](https://openjdk.org/jeps/372) hence you won't be able to use JavaScript language in later Java versions.